# VS Code: Best way to use custom wordlist for autocomplete

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, intellisense

I am using VS Code to write markdown files. Is there any way to use a wordlist with technical terms, which is stored in a separate folder outside the opened markdown project, for autocompletion?

At the moment the format of the wordlist with all technical terms is a text file which has on each line a particular term. However, it would be possible to reformat this file if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the extension [Complete from File](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.complete-from-file).

You have to define the languageID and files to use with a configuration in `settings.json`:

```json
  "complete-from-file.documents": {
    "markdown completions": {
      "documentSelectors": [{ "language": "markdown", "scheme": "file" }],
      "files": [
        "${workspaceFolder}${pathSeparator}markdown-complete.txt",
        "${userHome}${pathSeparator}completions${pathSeparator}markdown-complete.txt"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Each line of the file is used as a possible completion item. The file can contain comments (`//` and `#` lines) and empty lines. A completion line can contain any character (including spaces) but the initial characters must be word characters.

The default is that you need at least 3 characters to get a completion.
This setting can be changed (`complete-from-file.minimalCharacterCount`).

In Markdown files you have to request a completion with:
**Trigger Suggest** (key: `ctrl+space`, commandID: `editor.action.triggerSuggest`)

Answer (score 2):

If you have that wordlist open in your project, I would think that this setting should help:

```
Editor: Word Based Suggestions Mode  // set to allDocuments
```

That should suggest words from all open documents.

But you may need this in your `settings.json` as well:

```json
  "[markdown]": {
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
      "other": "on",
      "comments": "on",
      "strings": "on"
    }
  },
```

(I can't recall why just now but I believe you need special handling for markdown files.)  I do get completion suggestions if I do this.

Other wise you would probably have to make your extension with a `CompletionProvider` which incorporates your wordlist.

Comment: Mark do you know why Markdown files do not give automatic completion items? The `CompletionItemProvider` is called while typing for `plaintext` and `cpp`. For `markdown` you have to use `Ctrl+Space`

Comment: @rioV8 See my edit above about the additional setting - I remember having to do the markdown-specific setting even if those are already the settings for all files.  I don't remember why though...  Markdown handling has a few oddities.

Comment: why do they use both `suggestion` and `completion`, a bit confusing you have to search the settings for 2 key words for the same thing, or in the API it is completion and the UI it  is suggestion